# Editing crontab within python

Tags: python, cron

I have a RPi 3 running Raspbian Stretch.

My plan is to write a Python program to control a 4-relay module to switch lights on and off at predetermined times.

I’ve used tkinter to create a UI to select the on/off times which works fine.

I had hoped to use Python-crontab to create/edit a crontab within python, based on my UI selections which would call another python script to switch the lights on/off.

I installed python-crontab using:

```
pip install python-crontab
```

Which seemed to have been successful.

My Python script starts:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from crontab import CronTab
```

Which generates the ‘ImportError: No module named 'crontab'’

python-crontab seems just perfect for what I’m trying to do. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Perhaps it is Python2?  From the command line type python and at the prompt try import crontab.

Comment: This sounds promising!

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:48:08) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170124] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import crontab
>>> 

So no error! I'm using Thonny as my editor. Is there a way to force it to use Python 2.7.13? I've tried adding it to #!/usr/bin/ to no avail. Thanks very much for your help

Comment: Perhaps there is a Python3 version of the module (Python2 and Python3 are sufficiently different to need different modules).  The Debian convention is to use python3-xxx for Python3 modules.  Perhaps try `pip install python3-crontab`.

Comment: Fabulous help Joan! Thank-you! Using Python 2 (IDLE) python-crontab all seems to be working OK. importing Tkinter and my UI all seems to work too! I tried your suggestion for python3-crontab, but unfortunately it failed with 'No matching distribution found for python3-crontab' but hopefully I'll be able to do what I need in python 2. Again, thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`python-crontab` supports Python 3, but does need to be installed *for* Python 3. As noted in the [Pi docs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/software/python.md):

> pip3 installs modules for Python 3, and pip installs modules for Python 2.

If you would like to install `python-crontab` for Python 3, you must run:

```
sudo pip3 install python-crontab
```

It also appears to be available in the [Debian repositories](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/python3-crontab) for Python 3 (install with `sudo apt-get install python3-crontab`). It is a little outdated though at version 1.9.3 for Stretch, so if possible, pip is the preferable solution, which will install version 2.2.7.

---

Alternatively, if you wish for your script to be run using Python 2, you can change your [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to read:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

If you are able to use Python 3, though, it's generally advisable to use it — [Python 2 doesn't receive the latest updates](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3), and will, *eventually*, reach its end of life in 2020. Python 3 does have far fewer quirks, so I strongly advise you to consider using the methods above and install for Python 3 instead.

Comment: Excellent! I used sudo pip3 install python-crontab which has worked perfectly! That's a day I won't see again! Thanks again, it's much appreciated.

Comment: Actually, what has got it working in Thonny was using sudo apt-get install python3-crontab. Thanks again.